# TypeError: string indices must be integers error from api

Tags: python, api, dictionary

```
import requests 
y = requests.get("https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens/0x1f546ad641b56b86fd9dceac473d1c7a357276b7")
print(y["data"]["name"])
```

It's my code. api response is :

```
{"updated_at":1644149123565,"data":{"name":"PantherSwap Token","symbol":"PANTHER","price":"0.002859855069251732056933583434307","price_BNB":"0.000006871276102143279917041096829823"}}
```

i want to get only price and name. I mean `name = PantherSwap` and `price = 0.002859855`

when i run i have error, error is `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests 
response = requests.get("https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens/0x1f546ad641b56b86fd9dceac473d1c7a357276b7")
resp_json = response.json()
print(resp_json["data"]["name"])
```